# How to replace anything before and after curly brackets but keep content between them using PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, brackets

I need your help how can I remove anything after and before `curly brackets  {}` in `PHP`. But I don't want to remove `curly brackets` and content inside it so if there is anything after of before curly brackets.

I tried this:

```
 preg_replace('/.[^{]|[^\n{]+.+[^}|}]./', "", $string)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: @DipenShah Seems, that he wants to replace after and before and your question is about removing between.

Comment: @Tim Did you try anything? We want to see your efforts. It's a very simple task, that's why many people downvoted.

Comment: @user4035 look at OP statement `remove anything after { and before }` which would be the same as `between curly brackets`

Comment: @user4035 I am sorry I fail to understand the difference between both.

Comment: yes I tried this preg_replace('/.[^{]|[^\n{]+.+[^}|}]./', "", $string)
but not

Comment: @Tim You should have put it into the question. In this case you won't get downvotes. We gave a duplicate question with an answer for you. Does it work?

Comment: hello (I want to remove anything from here)  {"I am Tim"} (and from here)

Comment: @DipenShah Seems, that he wants to remove the text on external side of the brackets, not internal.

Comment: @Tim I edited your question and nominated it for reopening.

Comment: Yes user4035 I want to remove anything outside and I want to have only curly brackets with text inside similarly    "here is text symbols that I want ot remove"     {"I am Tim"} "I want to remove this text too" and after changes I want  only  {"I am Tim"}

Comment: How did you come up with that existing regex then? You could [**edit in**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31922822/edit) a few more detailed example strings/variables to highlight what you actually want. (Otherwise you'll perhaps get vague answers. And nobody here is obliged to answer shifting targets). -- You'll probably want to look into exempting `\K` alternative lists to skip `{…}` but remove the rest. Albeit just extracting strings per `preg_match_all()` would be heaps easier.

Answer (score 0):

Through this code you can replace anything after and before `curly brackets`

```
$string = preg_replace('#\{.*?\}#si', '', $string);
```

'

Comment: Hi Hasan, I just tried but it didn't work, it removed all content and left only the closing curly bracket. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This assumes non-nested braces.
Find:  `[^{}]*(\{[^{}]*\})[^{}]*`
Replace: `$1`

```
 [^{}]* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \{
      [^{}]* 
      \}
 )                             # (1 end)
 [^{}]*
```